# How to limit content by patch in AzerothCore

Tags: azerothcore

*Originally asked by DarkAvernus on Discord*

Is there a guide on how to limit content by patch? I'm looking to do progressive content for raids\arena seasons

Answer (score 1):

*Originally answered by Silker on Discord*

Yes, there is a guide: The AzerothCore wiki, take and read:

- https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/database-world - this one will have what you need.

You want to block raid/dungeon/maps/zones/that guy who eats pineapple pizza?

- Use: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/disables

You probably want to change items from vendors depending on patch like Wintergrasp or Dalaran rings:

- Use: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/npc_vendor

Want to disable emblem vendors in Dalaran? phase 'em..

- Use: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/creature#phasemask

Change emblems per boss through woltk content

- Use: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/creature_loot_template

Changing weekly quests (exp. 'x must die") and dungeon finder rewards?

- Here: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/quest_template

Arena seasons?

- Check the [worldserver.conf](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/worldserver/worldserver.conf.dist)

It's all about reading and understanding what to change, where and a lot of testing.

Furthermore, you can use editors like [Keira3](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3) that will help you generate the necessary SQL code